# creating a metrics table based on the counts of two other tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate

I have two tables that contain some analytics data.

```
table a_2_bb_2_ccc
    id_a
    id_bb
    id_ccc

table a_2_bb_2_dddd
    id_a
    id_bb
    id_dddd
```

I'm trying to find a good way to periodically cache the count of triplets in each table, into a unified third table that is keyed by the shared two elements:

```
table a_2_bb_cache
    id_a 
    id_bb
    count_ccc
    count_dddd
```

I can't wrap my head around this though.

I keep thinking of trying to solve this with single table groupings, and merging:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE a_2_bb_2_ccc__count AS
    SELECT
        id_a,
        id_bb,
        COUNT(id_ccc) AS count_ccc
    FROM
        a_2_bb_2_ccc
    GROUP BY id_a, id_bb
;

CREATE TEMP TABLE a_2_bb_2_dddd__count AS
    SELECT
        id_a,
        id_bb,
        COUNT(id_dddd) AS count_dddd
    FROM
        a_2_bb_2_dddd
    GROUP BY id_a, id_bb
;
```

however I can't be assured that any given (id_a, id_bb) combination is in one, or both, tables.  so all of my attempts to join give me the wrong data.

can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `full outer join`

```
select 
    id_a, 
    id_bb, 
    CASE WHEN count_ccc IS NOT NULL count_ccc ELSE 0 END,
    CASE WHEN count_dddd IS NOT NULL count_dddd ELSE 0 END
from
    (
        select
            id_a,
            id_bb,
            count(id_ccc) as count_ccc
        from a_2_bb_2_ccc
        group by id_a, id_bb
    ) sq1
    full outer join
    (
        select
            id_a,
            id_bb,
            count(id_dddd) as count_dddd
        from a_2_bb_2_dddd
        group by id_a, id_bb
    ) sq2 using(id_a, id_bb);
```

The `using` clause simplifies it as it makes its parameters unambiguous and non null. Otherwise, when using `on` it would be necessary to `coalesce` them.

Comment: ah! full outer join + two subqueries.  i kept trying to do this without a subquery and couldn't coalesce them right.   thanks so much!

Comment: i suggested an EDIT to your repsonse, adding a CASE and labeling the subqueries to make it valid postgres and use 0s for NULL joined counts.